# Using responsive variations in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

So I have been using, almost solely, `col-md-*` and then using media queries for responsiveness. However, would anyone recommend/ is there anything inherently wrong with setting the number of columns per break point (sm, md, lg, extra lg etc) everytime you do `col-*-*`?

Any tutorial I have ever done, seems to set for just one breakpoint, or occasionally for two, usually `col-md-*` and `col-sm-*`.

To me, I would imagine it may get a little messy in the html and perhaps become a touch tedious to do every time, but if i'm not mistaken, it would mean less hassle when it comes to media queries?

Thank you

Comment: Of course there is nothing inherently wrong with using multiple breakpoint classes. That is exactly what they are designed for. Writing your own media queries when bootstrap already has them built in is just pointless.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
Why do most people (that I have seen anyway) not do this then and rely far heavier on media queries?